# having an issue finding where exactly I activate an APK on the google developer console on google play

Tags: console, activation

hello guys I am uploading an app to google play for the first time and using a tutorial to test OBB downloading . while everything up until this point has worked like a charm so far the one issue and step i missed was activating an apk on google play. it looks like it should be as simple as a button but i don't see where exactly I should be disabling or enabling the option on the developer console  .

when i look for how others do it their consoles always look different from mine so am i even approaching this in the right place ? could there be a reason this option is hidden ?

here is a picture of where I am looking for this option on my console but i'm just not seeing it. any and all help is appreciated. it would be nice if i am just being blind and overlooking it or looking in the wrong place versus this being an error with my uploading the .apk